# Deploy changes CSS font value

Tags: css, .net, iis, deployment

I my project I use bootstrap. There is a CSS class called jumbotron.

> On my local IIS 10 is rendered ok :

[image]

> But when I deploy it to IIS 8 it changes the font size :

[image]

> Exactly the same code on both and they are both rendered on Firefox.

I noticed that locally my browser downloads 3 CSS for index page and after deploy they all get combined in one.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed bootstrap.css and after publish, the app used bootstrap.min.css. Moved my changes to a different css and it works now